# Objective C error: [BodyObject alloc]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c

I have been trying to use some objective C, i have got as far as creating a couple of objects and im now trying to instantiate them. The code compiles with no warnings but when it runs i get this in the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'-[CCSprite copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6424ad0'
```

Im guessing there is just a problem with the code somewhere, im not calling a copyWithZone method anywhere

Here is the code for game object:

gameobject.h

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box2D.h"

@interface GameObject : NSObject {

    }

-(id) initWithSprite:(CCSprite*) sprite
         andVelocity:(b2Vec2*) velocity;

@property (nonatomic, copy) CCSprite *Sprite;
@property (nonatomic) b2Vec2 *Velocity;

@end
```

gameobject.mm

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "GameObject.h"
#import "Box2D.h"

@implementation GameObject

@synthesize Sprite;
@synthesize Velocity;

-(id) initWithSprite:(CCSprite*) sprite
         andVelocity:(b2Vec2*) velocity
{
    self = [super init];

    self.Sprite = sprite;
    self.Velocity = velocity;

    return self;
}

@end
```

here is the code for BodyObject:

BodyObject.mm

```
#import "BodyObject.h"


@implementation BodyObject

@synthesize Body;
@synthesize Fixture;

-(id) initWithBody:(b2Body*) body 
        andFixture:(b2Fixture*) fixture 
       andVelocity:(b2Vec2*) velocity 
         andSprite:(CCSprite*) sprite
{
    self = [super initWithSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite 
                     andVelocity:(b2Vec2*)velocity];

    self.Body=body;
    self.Fixture=fixture;

    return self;
}

@end
```

BodyObject.h

```
#import "GameObject.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface BodyObject : GameObject {

}

@property (nonatomic) b2Body *Body;
@property (nonatomic) b2Fixture *Fixture;

-(id) initWithBody:(b2Body*) body 
        andFixture:(b2Fixture*) fixture 
       andVelocity:(b2Vec2*) velocity
         andSprite:(CCSprite*) sprite;

@end
```

And where im trying to instantiate it

```
BodyObject *bodyObject = [[BodyObject alloc] initWithBody:(b2Body *)body 
                                               andFixture:(b2Fixture *)fixture 
                                              andVelocity:(b2Vec2*) vector 
                                                andSprite:(CCSprite*) sprite];
```

Can anyone point me as to where to start looking for the solution for these types of errors or see a problem with the code? I can post more of the classes if required.

Thanks,

Comment: As a side-note, take out all the unnecessary casts. eg. initWithSprite:sprite andVelocity:velocity. Casting is extremely dangerous as it masks warnings - ie you can get any old crap to compile with zero warnings if you put enough casts in. You will need to use casts sometimes but only use them when there is a real need. Also, property names should always begin with lower-case

Comment: Thanks, I have amended the code and example. I think i must have put that there when I was trying to make the method work, there were colons all over the place!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong: `self = [[super initWithSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite andVelocity:(b2Vec2*)velocity] alloc];`

The right procedure is: `self = [super initWithSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite andVelocity:(b2Vec2*)velocity];`

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have changed the code above to: #import "BodyObject.h"


@implementation BodyObject

@synthesize Body;
@synthesize Fixture;

-(id) initWithBody:(b2Body*) body 
  andFixture:(b2Fixture*) fixture 
    andVelocity:(b2Vec2*) velocity 
   andSprite:(CCSprite*) sprite
{
 self = [[super alloc] initWithSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite 
        andVelocity:(b2Vec2*)velocity];
 
 self.Body=body;
 self.Fixture=fixture;
 
 return self;
}

@end but now i get the message: GameObject may not respond to -alloc

Comment: My mistake. You shouldn't have [super alloc] at all.. Is is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks it was the alloc method. i have updated the code to the latest version. trouble is im now getting a different error when running...*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCSprite copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6424ad0'. (also updated above) i dont think im calling this copyWithZone method anywhere!?

Comment: The problem is you're declaring the `Sprite` property as `copy` but `CCSprite` doesn't implement copying.  You probably don't want to declare the property that way.

Comment: The `+(id)alloc` method call is a Class method, not an instance one. Since it's the same for all instances of the class. Generally, you can think of it as the C `malloc(size_t size)` function, being the size given by the class.

Comment: Sorta;  there are actually a number of classes that override +alloc to return a placeholder instance that is then replaced in the instances `-init*` method.   Primarily, this is used in class clusters (`NSString` for example).

Comment: Yes, there may be some internal optimization and pre-processing during the `alloc` method, but i'm not fully aware of what kind of mechanisms are used.

Answer (score 1):

If you've reached the point in your code where your custom init methods are being called, then your object has already been allocated, so remove those outer calls to `+alloc` altogether.

(Also, unrelated, but the convention when naming selectors is not to include works like and, or, and but. Something like `-initWithSprite:velocity:` would conform to the Cocoa naming conventions.)

Comment: Thanks, it was the alloc method. I have just been trying to learn objective-c from a .net background so calling methods like that is very unusual to me at the moment!

Comment: No worries. :) It takes a while to transition.

Answer (score 1):

The likely reason for this crash is the CCSprite does not conform to NSCopying. If you either implement NSCopying on CCSprite (providing a copyWithZone: method) or change your Sprite property to retain, this crash will stop.

As a side note, accepted Objective-C style frowns upon any variable starting with a capital letter.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it! should I normally use retain for properties? I would mark as answer but Tiago was first to answer. +1 though :)

Comment: I'd say retain unless you definitely want to copy the object, or you are concerned that the object is mutable and another object may mutate it without your knowledge. There are a lot of considerations however.

Comment: properties invoke `[obj autorelease]` to the requested member which means that `obj` is added to an autorelease pool. Considering that this pool is drained at least once every thread loop, if you want to keep the object alive for more than that, you should retain it.

Comment: @tiago could you elaborate on that?

Comment: For each thread in the Cocoa framework you have at least one NSAutoreleasePool. When you do `obj.variable`, if you defined the property with the `retain` option, `variable` is added to the autorelease pool. At the end of each run loop, that pool is drained (releasing every object that was added) and thus, if you have an object retained only by that pool, that object is deallocated.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? That doesn't jive with my experience. If a property is marked retain, doing obj.variable = someVariable retains someVariable and there is no need for a further retain. Likewise, doing someVariable = obj.variable doesn't necessitate any further memory management. Am I missing something?